# Laravel 5.1 SSH - Unable to connect to remote server

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, ssh, sftp

I followed everything in this link here :

**Laravel 5.1 SSH**

`https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.1/ssh`

**Note:**

- `Key` is the key that I usally use to SSH into my VM.
- `Passphrase` also entered correctly.
- Local Env = Mac OS X
- username = bheng
- private key has set to 0600
- `-rw-------   1 bheng  staff    1766 Mar 10 13:25 id_rsa`
- public key has set to 0600
- `-rw-------   1 bheng  staff    1766 Mar 10 13:25 id_rsa.pub`

---

## config

```
'connections' => [
    'production' => [
        'host'      => '45.55.88.88',
        'username'  => 'root',
        'password'  => '',
        'key'       => '../id_rsa',
        'keytext'   => '',
        'keyphrase' => '*****',
        'agent'     => '',
        'timeout'   => 10,
    ],
],
```

---

I've tried a few more options :

**1. Place private key in same directory as the settings file**

```
'key'       => 'id_rsa',
```

**2. Place public key in same directory as the settings file**

```
'key'       => 'id_rsa.pub',
```

**3. Full path to private key**

```
'key'       => '/Users/bheng/.ssh/id_rsa',
```

**4. Full path to public key**

```
'key'       => '/Users/bheng/.ssh/id_rsa.pub',
```

---

## Usage

I tried run a simple `date` command.

`SSH::into('production')->run(['date']);`

---

## Result

I kept getting

> Unable to connect to remote server

---

## Questions

Did I forget anything ?
Is my configuration looks okay ?

How would one go about this continue debuging this ?

Comment: If you haven't explored this avenue yet, make sure that you have the correct permissions set on the key, and make sure that the user that Laravel is run as has the necessary permissions to use that key.

Comment: I am on my Mac OS, log in as myself, : user : me , and me have access to the key. I just chmod that key to **0600**

Comment: You might try hard coding they key path. It could be running it from an unexpected directory.

Comment: "Unable to connect to remote server" is a pretty vague error. You might be timing out, or getting a connection refused, or failing to authenticate.

Comment: @Kenster : will increase my timeout settings help ? How do I know if I am failing to authenticate or connection refuse ? Is there any logs file I can look into.

Comment: @Samsquanch : Ok. I will try and update you.

Comment: Surely the key should be your public key, not your private key?

Comment: I think private but I am not sure.

Comment: @Joe : I tried the public one, and still got same error.

Comment: @Samsquanch : I've tried full path to both private and public key, yet same answer. `/Users/bheng/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` and `/Users/bheng/.ssh/id_rsa`

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, your private key is not in PKCS1 format. Try to create a copy of your key and convert it:

```
cp ~/.ssh/id_rsa ~/.ssh/id_rsa_pkcs1

ssh-keygen -p -m PEM -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa_pkcs1
```

Then use `id_rsa_pkcs1` key in Rocketeer.